# Compile error being caused when using NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, nslayoutconstraint

My code is not compiling when I am using NSLayoutConstraint. I am trying to do everything with code and not using storyboard. I dont know if this is happening because I am missing something but it is nothining I can think of right now of why this is not working. The error is occurring in the viewDidLoad function at the `judo = line`.

I am getting the error:

> Cannot assign value of type '[()]' to type '[NSLayout

for the `judo = []` part.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var Judo1 = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    let FIRE = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(FIRE)
        FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let leadingc2 = FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        let trailingC2 =  FIRE.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        let topc2 =
            FIRE.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        let bottomc2 =   FIRE.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        Judo1 = [leadingc2,trailingC2,topc2,bottomc2]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(Judo1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the complete and exact error message (as text) and point out the line causing the error.

Comment: FYI - it is standard practice to name functions and variables using lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Ok I added my error.

Comment: That's not the complete error message. Please make the effort to provide complete, well formatted information to help ensure you get good answers.

Comment: you may also start var names with lower case letter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you append

```
 .active = true
```

no constraint returns so make them without `.active = true` as the return is void in this case

```
FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let leadingc2 = FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0)
let trailingC2 =  FIRE.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
let topc2 =   FIRE.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
let bottomc2 = FIRE.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)  
judo1 = [leadingc2,trailingC2,topc2,bottomc2] 
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(judo1)
```

A better way to use what apple recommends ( if you don't need a reference )

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([

   FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
   FIRE.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
   FIRE.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
   FIRE.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)

 ])
```

Also when constant is zero , get rid of it